# How to count number of times we can halve a number until it reaches 1?

Tags: python

I want to have a number that halves until it reaches 1, then it should return a count of how many times it halved.
example:

halve(4)
2

halve(11)
3

since 4/2 = 2 and 2/2= 1, hence it halved twice before reaching 1, and this is what I want it to return but my code isn't working, why? Can a modification be made ?

Here's my code

Python

```
def halve(n):

    i = 0 

    for i in range(n,1):
        if float(i/2) >=1:
            i+=1
        return i
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your code isn't working because the `return` statement is _inside_ the for loop, so the loop only executes one time.

Comment: Still isn't working after I put it outside !

Comment: for loop are used when you know how many times you want to do something. In your case you want a while loop, and the condition is to iterate while the number is greater than 1 `while n > 1:` inside the loop you want to divide n by 2 and **you need to update n**. `n = math.floor(n / 2)` . finally you need to increase a counter every time you loop `i += 1` so when the loop finished you know how many times you have iterated

Comment: Actually theres another reason your loop isn't working.  `i` is the loop variable and it is automatically assigned by the loop mechanism.  Updating that variable inside the loop as you do with `i += 1` is useless, because the loop itself overwrites `i`.

Comment: How do you determine that `halve(11)` returns `3`? How exactly do you want to handle things that don't divide evenly? For that matter, what would `halve(6)` return? Do you just want to divide until the result is less than 2?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you can employ some math and just write:

```
import math

def halve(n):
  return math.floor(math.log(n, 2))
```

You attempt is wrong for three reasons.

1. You are returning from within the loop. Thus it will never execute more than once.
2. Your loop will never execute unless `n` is `0` because `range` needs a third parameter as a negative number to increment "backwards."
3. The `i` assigned by your loop is shadowing the `i` you have previously assigned. Let's just use a `while` loop.

```
def halve(n):
    i = 0 
    while n/2 >= 1:
        i += 1
        n /= 2
    return i
```

Comment: maybe add an `abs` in there for safety?

Comment: Thank you Sembei, my logic was flawed. I was trying to increment i by 1 for everytime i/2 was greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Do you think i should've used a different variable instead of i for both iteration in the loop and increment value ?

Comment: Yes. If you don't care about the value, but just need to iterate a certain number of times, you can also: `for _ in ...: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to know what is wrong with your code:
First, immediate problem is that you return on first loop iteration. You need to return only when the number is smaller than 1 (so `if` condition is not met):

```
else:
    return i
```

Now, there is another problem - you are iterating over `range(n,1)` which... doesn't really make sense. You need way less than `n` divisions to reach number smaller than 1. Use a while loop instead - this way you loop as long as you need. You're also using `i` as an iterator, but also seem to be dividing it to see if it's more than one - shouldn't you use `n` there? You're also not reducing n, so you'd actually never reach n < 1.
Taking all of those your code might look like this:

```
    while True:
        if float(n/2) >=1:
            i+=1
            n /= 2
        else:
            return i
```

We can improve it even further - as you want your code to end if the condition is not met, we can simply move that to `while` condition:

```
def halve(n):

    i = 0 

    while float(n/2) >=1:
        i+=1
        n /= 2
    return i
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sembei Norimaki commented, a `while` loop is a more natural fit for this use case.

```
def halve(n):
    halves = 0
    while n > 1:
        n /= 2
        halves += 1
    return halves
```

This loop can be summarized "As long as n is greater than one, cut it in half and add one to the number of halves we have performed."

Comment: I don't understand why you have n/=2 ?

Comment: `n /= 2` is python shorthand for `n = n / 2`, just like `i += 1` is shorthand for `i = i + 1`.

Comment: You start with n and divide it by 2 as long as it's greater than 1. `n /= 2` is the same as `n = n / 2`